# Failover Config for SQL Server 2005 Professional on Win2k3 64x Standard (2 machines available)

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have MS SQL Server 2005 Standard on Win2k3 64x Standard (on 2 separate machines)

How to setup fail over cluster on this solution? I don't have neither SQL or Win Enterprise and it's too expensive to purchase :(

Any suggestions how to make synchronization between 2 MS SQL Servers running on different physical servers and switching from one to another in the case of fail of one server? DB is running for big amount of time and structure can't be changed a lot.

Thanks for help.

Comment: There is no "SQL Server 2005 Professional" edition... you mean "standard"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, "standard"

Answer (score -1):

You can't do failover clustering with your current configuration; the Standard edition of SQL Server is fine, but you would need the Enterprise Edition of Windows Server 2003. Also, some form of shared storage would be needed, which means additional hardware.

Your best bet with your available hardware and software would be to set up [Database Mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917681.aspx).

Comment: SQL 2k5 STD supports fail over clustering. You would need to install 2003 Enterprise to take advantage of it though.

Comment: So it doesn't support it with the OP's setup, correct? And if it is correct, why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, though partially true. OP's setup HALF supports the setup he wants. I would hate to see him spend the money on another version of SQL when what he has will work. You are correct though on needing to upgrade 2003 Server to ENT to take advantage of clustering.

On a side note, I'm also not sure what the proper ettiquette is here. When I down-voted, the site suggested I add a comment to clarify. If this bad practice, please forgive me in advance. :)

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity; now, changing your vote would be nice :-)